# Touch input (pen/finger) via TouchesBegan/TouchesMoved has big initial gaps

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin

I am developing an App for iOS. Latest versions of everything.

I'm adding some touch input - basically the ability to draw some shapes and highlight things. I have a UIScrollView which contains a UIView onto which other objects are drawn or placed. The UIView has a subview - a custom UIView which is the drawing canvas that covered its entirety.

I am catching the TouchesBegan/Moved/Cancelled/Ended routines in that canvas. Drawing, recording points, redrawing, varying line thickness on pressure, colours etc is working fine.

The weird thing is that I always get the -Began message, then *immediately* a -Moved message with a huge jump. Then things seem to settle down to smooth tracking with points received every 8-10ms.

Here is an example:
First - the call to TouchesBegan, in which I record the first point.

```
2020-11-09 10:16:51.094 PenApp[1499:449121] TouchBegan: Point(656.50, 380.00)
2020-11-09 10:16:51.094 PenApp[1499:449121] Added point: Point(656.50, 380.00), Vector(0.00, 0.00), width(1.00), timestamp(70488.92), speed(0.00), force(1.47)
```

Now the points get added during TouchesMoved. Note that the *first* point has an enormous jump (see the "Vector" which is the difference to the previous point). This occurs *inside* the same millisecond as the TouchesBegan (51.094). Then things settle down to smooth tracking.

```
2020-11-09 10:16:51.094 PenApp[1499:449121] Added point: Point(809.50, 518.50), Vector(153.00, 138.50), width(2.94), timestamp(70489.09), speed(1206.88), force(1.47)
2020-11-09 10:16:51.096 PenApp[1499:449121] Added point: Point(810.50, 525.00), Vector(1.00, 6.50), width(2.87), timestamp(70489.10), speed(1644.12), force(1.43)
2020-11-09 10:16:51.097 PenApp[1499:449121] Added point: Point(811.00, 531.00), Vector(0.50, 6.00), width(2.86), timestamp(70489.10), speed(1505.20), force(1.43)
2020-11-09 10:16:51.105 PenApp[1499:449121] Added point: Point(811.00, 536.00), Vector(0.00, 5.00), width(2.85), timestamp(70489.11), speed(1250.00), force(1.42)
2020-11-09 10:16:51.113 PenApp[1499:449121] Added point: Point(807.50, 551.50), Vector(-3.50, 15.50), width(2.84), timestamp(70489.12), speed(1222.33), force(1.42)
2020-11-09 10:16:51.122 PenApp[1499:449121] Added point: Point(805.50, 556.50), Vector(-2.00, 5.00), width(2.86), timestamp(70489.12), speed(1346.29), force(1.43)
```

I've seen other people comment on this first point gap, and have suggested skipping the first point(s). I can't simply ignore that first point - that is where I touch the pen/finger to the screen to start the curve. Skipping it results in a big gap before drawing starts (I tried it).  [Example of other person seeing problem](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/97875)

The impact is that my pen is actually tracking a curve during this whole time, but I get this huge initial gap in data, so even though I am actually using Beziers to draw curves (with varying thickness), the line I actually draw on the screen basically needs to be straight because of the lack of intermediate points. Here is an example - drawing started at the bottom:

[image: A curve with a large jump at the start]

I have no other threads running. This is very consistent - it happens on every drawing. I have no other events firing that I can see. I have a two fingered pan gesture recogniser set on the outer scroll view so I can move around - and I ignore multi-touch in the Touches- functions. However no multi-touch events are being raised.

Has anyone seen this and might have some pointers?
Thanks.
Paul

Addendum: I am experimenting with using a custom subclass of UIGestureRecognizer, and *its* TouchesBegan/TouchesMoved methods seem to be called correctly - without any large jumps at the start

Addendum^2: using the UIGestureRecognizer works beautifully, so I'll copy my code here. I wont add an answer because I dont think this answers the actual question (why do Touches* have big gaps) - instead this is more of a workaround. It doesn't quite feel write using a gesture to track drawing with a pen - my understanding is that they are more for high level operations (pan, object select, move etc).

```
public class DrawingGestureRecognizer : UIGestureRecognizer
{
    DrawingView canvas;
    bool LineActive = false;

    public DrawingGestureRecognizer(DrawingView _canvas) : base()
    {
        canvas = _canvas;
    }

    public override void TouchesBegan(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DrawingGestureRecognizer: TouchBegin");
        if (LineActive)
        {
            //  Looks line another line has started - probably a multi-touch starting.
            canvas.CurveCancelled(touches, evt);
            LineActive = false;
            return;
        }
        if (touches.Count != 1)
        {
            //  Multi-touch... so ignore.
            base.TouchesBegan(touches, evt);
            return;
        }
        LineActive = true;
        canvas.CurveBegan(touches, evt);
    }
    public override void TouchesMoved(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DrawingGestureRecognizer Moved");
        if (!LineActive || touches.Count != 1)
        {
            base.TouchesMoved(touches, evt);
            return;
        }
        canvas.CurveMoved(touches, evt);
    }
    public override void TouchesEnded(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DrawingGestureRecognizer Ended");
        if (!LineActive || touches.Count != 1)
        {
            //  A line was not active and we got an Ended message? Hand it on.
            //  If a line was active, but it switched to multitouch? Hand it on.
            base.TouchesMoved(touches, evt);
            LineActive = false;
            return;
        }
        canvas.CurveEnded(touches, evt);
        LineActive = false;
    }
    public override void TouchesCancelled(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DrawingGestureRecognizer Cancelled");
        if (!LineActive || touches.Count != 1)
        {
            base.TouchesCancelled(touches, evt);
            LineActive = false;
            return;
        }
        canvas.CurveCancelled(touches, evt);
        LineActive = false;
    }
}
```

In my DrawingView, I renamed Touches* to Curve* (e.g. TouchesBegan -> CurveBegan). My drawing is now nicely smooth - here is an example:

[image: Smooth curve, with force based width]

Comment: Hi, if this phenomenon exists when using `Touches`, you could also submit it [here(]https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues) in Github to ask for more help.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT - done.

Comment: Okey, you could share the link here, then others also can follow it up there.

Comment: Good point. https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/10072

Comment: @Paul Did you solve this issue ? Solutions Please

Comment: If you look at the solution... I mentioned that the Addendum^2 included the fix. TLDR; - use GestureRecognizers - they make movement smooth. I include code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the GitHub link in the comments: 
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/10072
the problem is likely inherent in iOS.

So the source code and solution outlined in Addendum #2 above
will solve this problem thoroughly.

So I think this one is closed.

Comment: Okey, if so you could mark this as the answer. Others will know the reason why shows in iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in an iOS app because the view I was capturing touch events in was embedded in a scroll view.

That could be fixed by setting ScrollView not delaying touch events:

```
scrollView.delaysContentTouches = false
```

Not sure how to do that in Xamarin though.